# Maintain drawing path on image with orientation changes in device android

Tags: android

I have issue for maintaining drawing (lines with use of finger) on image while device orientation changes.

This image shows the drawing on image with finger
[image]

After change the orientation, the draw line misplaced.
[image: This image shows drawing on image with finger]

I have path object which have this drawing data.

Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think pixel difference portrait and landscape mode... May be you can restrict rotation or clear existing when rotate

Comment: @GobuCSG, I want to maintain the drawing lines on their correct place when orientation change in device.

Comment: May be imageview scaletype fitcenter. I'm not sure

Comment: @GobuCSG, Nope this will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, It is obvious that landscape image's height is less than portrait one. So in this situation image is down scale. So we need to calculate using some equations to get that value which require to scale down the **Path** to adjust the position of that **Path**

To resolved this, Let's consider the portrait mode's image has H1 height and landscape mode's image has H2 height.

```
val scale = H2/H1
val matrix = Matrix()
matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
path.transform(matrix)
```

This way you will update the all the path objects for landscape mode.

Now when you rotate back to portrait mode, you need to undo scaling by below code.

```
val scale = 1 / (H2/H1)
val matrix = Matrix()
matrix.setScale(scale, scale)
path.transform(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try and let you know.